# How can I run a command line from a GTK app (C++) and redirect silmutaneously the output stream in a GTK object?

Tags: c++, redirect, gtk, stdout

I'm building a **graphical interface using C++ and GTK 3.0**.
From this, I would like to **run another C++ program** (let's call it BOB) and **get the STDOUT and STDERR informations *simultaneously* on my interface**.

The command line to run BOB from a console is :
*./BOB_executable_file parameter_file*
I manage to run it from the interface, with **popen()** or **g_spawn_command_line_sync()** and the outputs are printed directly into the console (I launched the interface from the console).

The best I managed to have is to have the command line running but which need to be completely finished so the outputs can be printed : **it's not direct and simultaneous redirection**...

- redirect the STDOUT and STDERR into files with **popen()**:

  ```
    //command line storing STDOUT and STDERR into files
    const gchar* command = ("./BOB_executable_file param_file > FATE_stdout.txt 2>FATE_stderr.txt").c_str();
    //running the command
    FILE* pipe = popen(command,"r");

    string temp, line;
    gchar* res;
    GtkWidget* pLabel;

    //opening the STDOUT file
    ifstream file("FATE_stdout.txt", ios::in);
    while (getline(file,line)){ //for each line read from the file
        temp = line;
        res = g_locale_to_utf8(temp.c_str(),-1,NULL,NULL,NULL); //convert it to utf8
        pLabel = gtk_label_new(NULL); //create an empty label
        gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(pLabel),res); //update the label with the line
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(myBox), pLabel, TRUE, TRUE, 0); //add the label to myBox which is a vertical box
        gtk_widget_show_all((GtkWidget*) data); //show the new line
    }
  ```
- redirect the STDOUT and STDERR into objects with **g_spawn_command_line_sync**:

  ```
    gchar *output_txt, *error_txt;       
    GError *error = NULL;

    //command line storing STDOUT and STDERR into files
    const gchar* command = ("./BOB_executable_file param_file > FATE_stdout.txt 2>FATE_stderr.txt").c_str();
    //running the command
    g_spawn_command_line_sync(command, &output_txt, &error_txt, NULL, &error);

    if (error != NULL){
        errorMessage(error->message);  
        g_error_free(error);
        return;
    }

    //add the label to myBox1 and myBox2 which are vertical boxes
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(myBox1), gtk_label_new(output_txt), TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(myBox2), gtk_label_new(error_txt), TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show_all((GtkWidget*) data);
  ```

**BUT** in both cases, the command line has to be completely finished so the outputs can be printed : **it's not direct and simultaneous redirection**...

I also tried to use **GIO stuff** (I tried with STDOUT and STDERR files created either with **g_spawn_command_line_sync()** or **g_spawn_async_with_pipes()** or **popen**) but it's still not simultaneous and the interface crashes :

```
      GIOChannel* outchannel = g_io_channel_new_file("FATE_stdout.txt","r",NULL);
      g_io_add_watch (outchannel, (GIOCondition)(G_IO_IN), on_pipe_output, (gpointer) view_output);

      GIOChannel* errchannel = g_io_channel_new_file("FATE_stderr.txt","r",NULL);
      g_io_add_watch (errchannel, (GIOCondition)(G_IO_ERR), on_pipe_output, (gpointer) view_error);
```

with *view_output* and *view_error* some TextView with buffers inside and the listening function *on_pipe_output* :

```
      void scroll_to_end(GtkWidget* textview){
        GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
        GtkTextIter enditer;

        buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textview));
        gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER (buffer), &enditer);
        gtk_text_view_scroll_to_iter(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textview), &enditer, 0, TRUE, 0.0, 0.0);
      }

      void addMsgInfo(GtkWidget* textview, gchar *buf){
        GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
        GtkTextIter  enditer;

        buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textview));
        gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (GTK_TEXT_BUFFER (buffer), &enditer);
        gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &enditer,buf,-1);
        g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc)scroll_to_end, NULL);
      }

      gboolean on_pipe_output (GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data){
        gchar buffer[BUFSIZ+1];
        gsize *bytes_read;
        g_io_channel_read_chars(source,buffer,BUFSIZ,bytes_read,NULL);

        addMsgInfo((GtkWidget*) data, buffer);
      }
```

Does anyone have already deal with such problem and has a solution or improvement ?